# DEPRECATION WARNING: The `Validator#setup` instance method is deprecated and will be removed on Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know what this warning is ? Please suggest something.
Given below is part of my application code.
It gives me error on statement with validates_date line.

Rails suggest me the do something like:

```
class MyValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def initialize(options={})
    super
    options[:class].send :attr_accessor, :custom_attribute
  end
end
```

This is the code of application below:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick index_name: "patients",text_start: [:first_name,:last_name] 
  after_update :reindex
  has_secure_password
  has_many :addresses
  has_many :vitals
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "150x150>", :thumb => "50x50>" },   :default_url => "app/assets/images/missing.png"

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  validates :email, email_format: {message: "Invalid email format" }

  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  validates :password_digest, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: {minimum: 8,message:"Must be of atleast 8 characters"}

  validates :first_name, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, message: "First Name should contain only alphabets"}

  validates :last_name, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, message: "Last Name should contain only alphabets" }

  validates_date :dob,:before => lambda { Date.current }, presence: true

  validates :password_digest, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: {minimum: 8,message:"Must be of atleast 8 characters"}

  validates :primary_phone_no, presence: true,numericality: {only_integer: true}
end
```

Comment: Please don't downvote I need help regarding this issue of rails 4.2 just upgraded from 4.1 and now getting this error.

Comment: I think you meant you just upgraded **to** 4.1 which just came out.  This is just a warning of code that will eventually disappear in 4.2.

Comment: Yup sorry for wrong comment above upgraded to 4.1 from 4.0.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to worry right now.  I see from `validates_date` you are using the `validates_timeliness` gem - it's that gem that is currently throwing the deprecation warning.

It is an open issue on that gem and it's being worked on - this is the current open issue: https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/pull/114

I suggest you just wait until they fix it and then update the gem.  It's just a warning and won't stop anything working right now.

Comment: This gem seems to be unmaintained. There's now a fork, compatible to Rails 4.+

See https://github.com/johncarney/validates_timeliness